# Pandas compare column in same data frame and replace values based on comparison

Tags: python, pandas

I have a excel sheet that consist of over 6000 rows. There are two column , "IP Address CMDB" that contain IP addresses and another column called "IP Address LM".
I am trying to look for IP address that belongs to "IP Address CMDB" in "IP Address LM" and if "IP Address LM" contain that IP address return ABCD.
I could not attach excel sheet so I have attached screenshot of it.

[image]

```
for col in report:
    if col == "IP Address CMDB":
        col_num = report[col]
        for num in col_num:
            if report["IP Address LM"].str.contains(num):
                print("ABCD")
<ipython-input-13-40cfae2bd937>:5: UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.
  if report["IP Address LM"].str.contains(num):
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-40cfae2bd937> in <module>
      3         col_num = report[col]
      4         for num in col_num:
----> 5             if report["IP Address LM"].str.contains(num):
      6                 print("ABCD")
      7 

c:\users\rohit verma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1535     @final
   1536     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1537         raise ValueError(
   1538             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1539             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the below code to check whether the **IP Address LM** contains what belongs to **IP Address CMDB**:

```py
checkColumn = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  Ip = row["IP Address LM"]
  toCheck = row["IP Address CMDB"]
  if toCheck in Ip:
    checkColumn.append("ABCD")
  else:
    checkColumn.append(None)
df["check"] = checkColumn
```

##### Explanation

`iterrows()` function loops over all of the dataframe's rows. Then using a logic statement such as `toCheck in Ip` we are trying to check whether the value exists in the abovementioned column or not. If not, returns `None`, otherwise, returns `ABCD` as requested.

Answer (score 0):

As the source DataFrame (*report*) I created:

```
                        IP Address CMDB IP Address LM
0                   10.1.0.36,10.1.53.1     10.1.0.36
1                            10.1.11.21    10.1.11.21
2  10.1.148.20,192.168.128.3,10.1.5.130    10.1.5.130
3                            10.1.5.100    10.1.5.140
4                            10.1.6.120    10.1.6.140
```

To identify rows where *IP Address CMDB* contains *IP Address LM* you can run e.g.:

```
report.apply(lambda row: row['IP Address LM'] in row['IP Address CMDB'], axis=1)
```

Details:

1. `report.apply` - applies the given lambda function to each **row** (due
   to *axis=1* parameter).
2. `row['IP Address LM'] in row['IP Address CMDB']` - creates temporary
   lists of characters from both columns in the current row and checks
   whether the left list is contained in the right one.
3. The returned value actually answers your question (does *IP Address CMDB*
   contain *IP Address LM*).

The result is:

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

As you can see, *IP Address CMDB* in first 3 rows contains *IP Address LM* from the current row.

If you want to do something more, write your own function including
your actions, returning some result for the current row,
and replace the lambda function with this function.

And a note about your code:
*str.contains* can be used to check whether an element of a column contains
a **fixed** value, but you actually want to check containment for values
in the **current** row only.